# Why can't we use *.cshtml files as custom error pages now that (v4.7) we have "Razor Web Pages"?

Tags: asp.net, razor, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-error-pages

B"H

Trying to revamp my global error handling, and running into the mess that is ASP.net error handlers.

I would really like to consolidate my solution as much as possible. So if possible I'd like to use the same pages to display from `httpErrors` and `customErrors`. I'd also like to use the appropriate `Layout` pages if possible. But it seems that if I want to use some kind of dynamic page as a custom error page that it needs to be *.aspx. Why is that? Especially now that we have Razor Web Pages?

PS. This is for an MVC (.net v4.7 ie not asp core) Site

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the .cshtml file as a Razor Web Page, then can't you give the URL of the file, excluding the .cshtml?  As per the table here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio

A standalone .cshtml file is will normally depend on a Code behind file (if using Razor Web Pages) or a MVC Controller Action to provide it with its data.  I guess this is why you are not allowed to redirect directly to one.